# How can I turn X,Y,Z,Value data into an array in python?

Tags: python

I want to take `x`,`y`,`z`,value data, where `x`,`y`,`z` are positions and value is a number in a very long list and transform it into an array where each position on the array is represented by `x`,`y`,`z` and the number is the value. For example:

```
1,1,1,27
2,2,2,38
```

would mean that `array[1,1,1] = 27` and `array[2,2,2] = 38`.

How can I do this effectively, please?

The data comes from a csv file, length 2000. Easy to handle. There will be some overlap in indicies, but we need to average the value line for each –
for example 1.3,1,1,27 and 1.2,1,1,28 should become array[1,1,1] = 27.5

Comment: as you can not use numbers as an array , you have to use a dictionary instead.

Comment: could you please make an example of how you get these data?
e.g., from a file, from some input...?
Do you know a priori how many data you will have to handle? Are you sure that there will be no conflict between indices?

Comment: The data comes from a csv file, length 2000. Easy to handle. There will be some overlap in indicies, but we need to average the value line for each

Comment: for example 1.3,1,1,27 and 1.2,1,1,28 should become array[1,1,1] = 27.5

Comment: That would be relevant information in your question... Not a comment

Answer (score 0):

as you can not use number as an array(or list) , you have to use a dictionary instead.
try this:

```
listData        = '1,1,1,27// 2,2,2,38'
partition       = list(map(str.split,listData.split("//")))
lastDict        = {}
for i,it in enumerate(partition):
    xyzV        = it[0].split(',')
    lastDict[xyzV[-1]] = (xyzV[0] , xyzV[1] , xyzV[2])
print(lastDict)
```

the outPut will be like:

```
{'27': ('1', '1', '1'), '38': ('2', '2', '2')}
```

i hope it was helpful

**UPDATE**

as you change the separator of the datas from "//" to new line , you can use instead of '//' in split, use "\n"

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it needs to be an array though, as I need to compute array multiplication using this. Is there a way I can go from a dictionary to an array?

Comment: u cant name an array (or list) just in numbers, u just can refer it to a number , something like that i wrote for you

Comment: @sw149282 It can be a 3-dimensional list/array and access it as `arr[x][y][z]`. Problem with that is that you need to have it initialized in the proper size

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3-D array. If the data is coming from a CSV file, something like below could work. As @Tomerikoo pointed out, you would need to initialize the 3d array first:

```
import csv 


sizeX = 0
sizeY = 0
sizeZ = 0
rawData = []

with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for line in reader:
        x, y, z, val = list(map(int, line.split(',')))
        rawData.append((x,y,z,val))
        sizeX = max(sizeX, x)
        sizeY = max(sizeY, Y)
        sizeZ = max(sizeZ, Z)

mat = [[[None]*sizeX for _ in range(0, sizeY)] for __ in range(0, sizeZ)]

for data in rawData:
    # average out the old value if old value exists
    if mat[data[0]][data[1]][data[2]] is not None:
        mat[data[0]][data[1]][data[2]] = (mat[data[0]][data[1]][data[2]] + data[3])/2
    else:
        mat[data[0]][data[1]][data[2]] = data[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This I think solves the issue for all those interested

```
countArray = np.zeros((int(np.max(xpos)+2),int(np.max(ypos)+2),int(np.max(zpos)+2)))
totalArray = np.zeros((int(np.max(xpos)+2),int(np.max(ypos)+2),int(np.max(zpos)+2)))

for n in range(totalLines):
 
    if n==lines: print(maxx,maxy,maxz,n,n/lines)
    nx = int(round(xpos[n]))
    ny = int(round(ypos[n]))
    nz = int(round(zpos[n]))

    countArray[nx,ny,nz] += counts[n]
    totalArray[nx,ny,nz] += 1
    if nx > maxx: maxx = nx
    if ny > maxy: maxy = ny
    if nz > maxz: maxz = nz
    
    
    maxx += 1
    maxy += 1 
maxz += 1                

for x in range(totalArray.shape[0]):
    for y in range(totalArray.shape[1]):
        for z in range(totalArray.shape[2]):
            if(totalArray[x,y,z]==0):
                totalArray[x,y,z]=1
                   
scanDataArray = np.divide(countArray[0:maxx,0:maxy,0:maxz],totalArray[0:maxx,0:maxy,0:maxz])
```